# Hawtio remote connect configuration parameters not correct for monitoring remote machine

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio, jolokia

My goal is to confirm that one can use a Hawtio instance to monitor an instance running on a different machine.

I am using this example https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-camel-wiki .

right now i have it running on my local machine in OSX and on a remote Ubuntu 18 machine. I try to connect them however i cant seem to monitor the instance on the other machine.

I then tried to just use the hawtIO jar to connect to that example running on the remote machine.

I first set my hawtio.proxyWhitelist or hawtio.proxyAllowList (i also tried using the hawtio JAR on my local machine) to whitelist the endpoints. (2.10 uses the former)

```
java -Dhawtio.proxyAllowlist=* -jar hawtio-app.jar
```

My issue is i am not sure what to put in the connection tabs. I have been trying port 61613 and the path as /api/jolokia but i cant seem to figure out where its running to connect to it.

Comment: hawtio-camel-wiki is an archived project which is not relevant any longer so please don't use it. As to what info you need to put in the Connection tab, it depends on what remote JVMs you'd like to connect to. Generally they should provide a Jolokia endpoint with a specific port and path which you should input to the connection info.

Comment: what would be a good jolokia project to bootstrap to test out that i can connect hawtio remotely? and what are the default paths and ports that jolokia runs on thanks @TadayoshiSato

Comment: You can check https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html. If you already have something to run, the JVM agent should be the easiest option. You can also check some Spring Boot examples here: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/hawtio-2.10.1/examples

Comment: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1026 i cant seem to get those examples to build do you know where in the pom.xml the build number is @TadayoshiSato ?

Comment: Use repository tag hawtio-2.10.1 instead of master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hawtio-camel-wiki is an outdated project which was archived quite a while ago and is not relevant any longer. As to what info you need to put in the Connection tab, it depends on what remote JVMs you'd like to connect to. Generally speaking, they should provide a Jolokia endpoint with a specific port (e.g. `8080`) and path (e.g. `/jolokia`) which you should input to the connection info.

For how to incorporate a Jolokia endpoint into your application, you can check https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html. If you already have something to run, the JVM agent should be the easiest option.

You can also check some Spring Boot examples here:
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/hawtio-2.10.1/examples

Comment: i cant seem to find the hawtio-web  folder to build the code myself. i am using tag  tag hawtio-2.10.1 and i also tried your newest one as well.

Comment: the only branch where i noticed this web folder was in tag/hawtio-0.1

Comment: Since Hawtio v2 hawtio.war is built in hawtio-war instead of hawtio-web.

Comment: So if i wanted to experiment with modifying the front end angular code to rebuild it i would look there and follow the same build instructions? I dont see any angular code in hawtio-war.

Comment: Internally, hawtio-war depends on hawtio-console-assembly that assembles the js plugin components which are hosted in other repos: hawtio/hawtio-core and hawtio/hawtio-integration. You can find the angular code in those projects.